# android app does not crash after 6 seconds

Tags: java, android

I created a button and placed the following code in my MainActivity:

```
public void pauseitjack(View v)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(16000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I pressed on the button and it did freeze my UI which is what I expected, but the app idd not crash. I though this would crash my app after 5 second with an ANR error...

Comment: Why did you expect a crash?  What would've caused it? What would be the underlying exception / error? (I'm **not** saying that you were wrong - just clarifying for myself).

Comment: as i understand it, if the UI is stuck for more than 5 seconds, app will crash

Comment: Can you please provide authoritative link(s) for this statement and clarify the criteria for "stuck"?

Comment: No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every device has the watchdog timer set to the same length, and not all functions have a watchdog.  Also, sleep allows the processor to switch tasks, so it probably won't set off a watchdog anyway.  Its still a bad idea to sleep on the UI thread though.

Comment: can you explain to me how i can turn on this watchdog ?

Comment: You wouldn't.  Its a system thing, the OS puts it on some functions (like onCreate) to prevent them for taking too long and providing the appearance of a broken phone.  Why are you trying to crash anyway?

Comment: well, I want to know which methods gets called(onPause, onResume..etc) when an app crashes... perhaps you know ?

Comment: When an app crashes, the normal flow of events is affected. In case of a crash, the activity is killed by the Android environment without calling onPause(), onResume(), onDestroy() or anything.

Comment: A crash is a crash.  Nothing gets called, the process is immediately killed.  Also, if you wanted to just crash the easiest way to do it would be to just throw an Exception and not catch it.

Comment: just tried it right now, your right - nothing gets called.

Comment: so then what is this 5 second rule i have been reading about - that it will give ANR after 5 seconds... how can I force this to happen  ?

Comment: That would be the watchdog timer.  It only applies to some functions.  Try putting an infinite loop (Not a sleep) in onCreate.

Comment: i did try infinite for -loop , i nested 2 of them, still didn't crash,.. but then again i just cancelled everything after like 5 minutes

Comment: this documentation must be wrong: we should use a background thread to do work that could take a while. Android forces us into this position because if the main thread does not handle something within 5 seconds, an Application Not Responding (ANR)condition will be triggered - book: pro android 4

Comment: The reason is wrong.  The idea isn't.  The reason you do it on another thread is that it would otherwise make the app and phone non-responsive.  The crash may or may not happen, depending on how the OEM set up the phone (whether they decided to enable a watchdog or not, some phones definitely will crash).

Answer (score 0):

An ANR will happen when you don't respond to touch commands in time.

In your case if you only push the button once it won't cause ANR, but if you push the button a second time while the sleep is running, then the system will try to send the touch to your button and you won't respond on time because of sleep, causing an ANR.